# Сборник полезных комментариев

Tags: предложение, комментарии, шаблонные-комментарии

Довольно утомительно каждому новичку объяснять одно и тоже: "приведи код картинкой", "что не так с кодом" и т. д.

Поэтому я решил создать здесь, на мете, сборник часто используемых шаблонных комментариев.

Правила оформления:

```markdown
 + <СИТУАЦИЯ, КОГДА КОММЕНТАРИЙ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ПОЛЕЗЕН>.
   > `<ШАБЛОН>`

[  > `<ЕЩЁ ОДИН ШАБЛОН>`

...]

---
```

Добавляйте ваши шаблоны!